# Object in compilation Handlebars in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

In example, i have this app (templates content below): http://pastebin.com/NGJgp6hG

After renedering page he output next:

```
<div class="container">
    [Object object] 
</div>
```

But if i change in 31 line to:

```
this.$el.html(this.template({ value: this.section.render().$el.html() }))
```

**Or** in 43 line to:

```
this.$el = this.template({ value: "Some val" });
```

It output section.hbs template with included data.

I think it is not normal, to render template such corrections (Router render Module template right).

Answer (score 0):

You're right that by default, it would seem that your `template` method should be returning a function to be called not a compiled template.

But you replace `template` in the pastebin with some other array called `jst`, which clearly contains functions.